# CheckboxList ignores DataValueField and DataTextField

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

I found the bug. It was so plain in sight: I'm not databinding to the correct checkboxlist! I should have been databinding to filterONTYPElist, but i'm databinding to the filterONDATASETlist... Copy paste error, sorry...

I have a checkboxlist that renders as follows:

[image]

Here is the code that handles the databinding:

```
FilterOnTypeCheckboxList.DataSource = listCheckboxItems;
FilterOnDatasetCheckboxList.DataValueField = "Value";
FilterOnDatasetCheckboxList.DataTextField = "Text";
FilterOnTypeCheckboxList.DataBind();
```

My datasource is a `list<CheckBoxItem>`. That class looks as follow, and you can clearly see there is a public property Value and a public property Text:

```
[Serializable]
public class CheckboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public CheckboxItem(string value, string text)
    {
        Value = value;
        Text = text;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "brompot";
    }
}
```

But for some reason, the text AND value for each checkbox uses the ToString() method of the CheckBoxItem class, rather then the appropiate property "Value" and "Text".

PS: I checked that the value and the text of the checkboxitems objects is not the string "brompot"...

It is not an option to let the toString() method return the text OR the value, because I want the checkbox value to be the value property and the checkbox (label) text

Answer (score 3):

I ran a quick test and this seems to work as expected. 
Could you please provide more details? Also, verify if the code that I provide is similar to what you are doing?

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnBind" runat="server" Text="Bind" OnClick="btnBind_Click" />
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>


public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void btnBind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CheckboxItem> listCheckboxItems = new List<CheckboxItem>();
        listCheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem("Val-1", "Item-1"));
        listCheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem("Val-2", "Item-2"));
        listCheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem("Val-3", "Item-3"));
        listCheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem("Val-4", "Item-4"));
        listCheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem("Val-5", "Item-5"));

        this.cbList.DataSource = listCheckboxItems;
        this.cbList.DataValueField = "Value";
        this.cbList.DataTextField = "Text";
        this.cbList.DataBind();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class CheckboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public CheckboxItem(string value, string text)
    {
        Value = value;
        Text = text;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "brompot";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, only I'm not seeing the value or the text, but whatever is returned by the toString() method. If I don't specify an toString() method, c# takes the default ToString() method which returns the class name of "CheckBoxItem". What could I be overlooking?

Comment: This is just a guess, but try removing the [Serializable] tag of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is because of your `ToString()` method.

Edit to be this and see if that fixed your problem:

```
[Serializable]
public class CheckboxItem
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }

  public CheckboxItem(string value, string text)
  {
      Value = value;
      Text = text;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Text;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but your proposed solution has the problem that both the value and the textfield would become equal to "text".